# Legend of Grimrock text unreadable on 4k screen

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I just installed [GOG LoG](https://www.gog.com/game/legend_of_grimrock) on Linux, and it looks like the fonts don't scale with the resolution. Are there any mods, replacement fonts or hidden settings to be able to read the text on a high resolution monitor?

I'm using the Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers, in case there are any tricks. As far as I can tell none of the options in the custom application profiles are relevant.

So far I've searched the [official forums](http://grimrock.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=4), [Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/207170/discussions/), [GOG troubleshooting guide](https://support.gog.com/hc/en-us/articles/214064185-Legend-of-Grimrock?product=gog), [install directory]/game/README.linux and ~/.local/share/Almost\ Human/Legend\ of\ Grimrock/grimrock.cfg.

(Changing the screen resolution is a possibility, but definitely a last resort.)